# Will Windows 10 Reset Damage Ubuntu?(Dual boot PC)

Tags: grub2, kubuntu, windows-10

I have a dual boot pc and want to know if windows 10 reset will damage kubuntu grub menu where I choose which system to run. And if yes - how to fix it.

Thank you...

Comment: In depends on the installation mode. If BIOS then it's very likely. If UEFI then probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your installation is UEFI based then you'll probably be OK. If your system is BIOS based, resetting Windows might corrupt GRUB bootloader. In that case find out in which partition Ubuntu is installed on (like sda3 or sda2. Use the app **GParted**. It is probably the biggest partition with ext4 format). Note it down. Make a [bootable](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/) CD/DVD/USB drive with Ubuntu (or Kubuntu) iso. Then reset Windows. If GRUB is toast after the reset then boot from that CD/DVD/USB drive you've made and follow instructions from [this](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) link.